# Why are the softmax, softplus, and softsign functions all prefixed with the word soft?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, terminology

Also, in practice, are the softplus and softsign functions ever used as the activation functions in neural networks?

Comment: I guess the key is the difference between a soft landing and a hard landing....

Comment: Because they have smooth derivatives instead of points of undefined derivatives or flat regions to be trapped which are harmful for optimizers. They are extensively used in deep networks.